# QR Decomposition; Division By Zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise: *QR factorize the matrix
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$*

I tried to apply the Gram - Schmidt process
$$\begin{array}{rr}
q_{1}=a_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}, & \hat{q_{1}}=\frac{1}{\left\Vert q_{1}\right\Vert }q_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\\
q_{2}=a_{2}-\frac{\left\langle q_{1},a_{1}\right\rangle }{\left\Vert q_{1}\right\Vert ^{2}}q_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}, & \text{It can't be normalized}\\
q_{3}=a_{3}-\frac{\left\langle q_{1},a_{3}\right\rangle }{\left\Vert q_{1}\right\Vert ^{2}}q_{1}-\frac{\left\langle q_{2},a_{3}\right\rangle }{\left\Vert q_{2}\right\Vert ^{2}}q_{2}, & \text{Indeterminate}
\end{array}$$
but I ended up having to divide by zero. I checked with various calculators online, and the resulting matrices should be
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }R=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

How are the matrices above the correct answer, since we have to divide by zero to complete the proccess?

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt algorithm takes a linearly independent set $\{{\bf v}_a\}$ of vectors and returns an orthonormal basis of $\operatorname{span} \{{\bf v}_a\}$. The columns of $A$ are not linearly independent, so, as you've observed, the Gram-Schmidt algorithm doesn't work after encountering the first vector ${\bf v}_a$ in the span of previous vectors, ${\bf v}_1, \ldots, {\bf v}_{a-1}$.

Comment: You use Gram Schmidt to normalize "linearly independent" vectors. In your case, columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: $q_1=q_2$ so you should not be using Gram-Schmidt to calculate it as you cannot orthogonally project one onto the other.

Comment: As a matter of language, usually I see the decomposition of a degenerate $n \times n$ matrix $A$ into a product of an $n \times m$ matrix and an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m := \operatorname{rank} A$, called something like the *reduced QR decomposition*. If you were looking for square matrices (what's usually meant when one talks about the QR decomposition without qualification), then since $A$ is already upper triangular, you could just take $Q = I$, $R = A$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did a little research, and went with the answer @TravisWillse suggested.